# C# Reflection dynamically create concrete class instance of T

Tags: c#, reflection, activator

I want to do something at runtime with objects based on there type.
Depending on the type I need to do different operations so I thought I would create
an abstract class like this:

```
internal abstract class DataOperator<T>
        where T : class
    {
        public abstract void DoSomething(IList<T> data);
    }
```

with multiple concrete implementations like:

```
class MyClassOperator : DataOperator<MyClass>
     
    {
        public override void DoSomething(IList<MyClass> data)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

But how would I actually create an instance of the concrete class at runtime?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using reflection. Instead, you'd write a factory class which has methods to create the concrete classes, in a way where the consumers only receive the abstract class.

Comment: "_But how would I actually create an instance of the concrete class at runtime?_" `new MyClassOperator()` or `new MyClass()` (depending on which class you meant by writing "_concrete class_"). Not sure where this idea of needing reflection for such things is coming from...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace well the thing is that I don't know which class to instantiate up front. I need to create an instance of DataOperator depending on T

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `DataOperator<A>` and `DataOperator<B>` are not assignment compatible. Not even if `A` and `B` are. So, you cannot assign your classes to, say `DataOperator<object>`. Therefore, you will have to treat them individually as non related types.

A way out is to have a non generic base type or interface.

```cs
interface IDataOperator
{
    public void DoSomething(IList data);
}
```

We create an abstract class that implements it explicitly in order to hide this weakly typed `DoSomething` when not called through the interface. We also introduce the generic type parameter.

```cs
abstract class DataOperator<T> : IDataOperator
    where T : class
{
    void IDataOperator.DoSomething(IList data)
    {
        if (data is IList<T> listT) {
            DoSomething(listT);
        } else {
            throw new ArgumentException("The List is not compatible.", nameof(data));
        }
    }

    abstract public void DoSomething(IList<T> data);
}
```

We implement concrete types like this:

```cs
class DataOperatorA : DataOperator<MyClassA>
{
    public override void DoSomething(IList<MyClassA> data)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class DataOperatorB : DataOperator<MyClassB>
{
    public override void DoSomething(IList<MyClassB> data)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

These implementations are assignment compatible to our interface. Example:

```cs
IDataOperator[] operators = { new DataOperatorA(), new DataOperatorB() };
```

---

If you want to create different operators depending on other data, you can create a factory class. In this example, we use a string as discriminator, but it could be anything else, like a `System.Type` or an enum, etc.

```cs
static class DataOperator
{
    public static IDataOperator Create(string op)
    {
        return op switch {
            "A" => new DataOperatorA(),
            "B" => new DataOperatorB(),
            _ => throw new ArgumentException("Unknown operator.", "op")
        };
    }
}
```

Same example as above but with the factory:

```cs
IDataOperator[] operators = { DataOperator.Create("A"), DataOperator.Create("B") };
```

Comment: Thanks, that would be another approach yes.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue using a factory as suggested by Matthew Watson.
`DataOperator` is actually `AggregateRootMigrator`

```
 public static class AggregateRootMigratorFactoryProvider
    {
        public static AggregateRootMigrator<T> GetAggregateRootMigrator<T>()
            where T : AggregateRoot
        {
            var type = typeof(AggregateRootMigrator<T>).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(
                t =>
                    {
                        if (t.IsAbstract == false && t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AggregateRootMigrator<T>)))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }

                        return false;
                    }).SingleOrDefault();

            if (type == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"No Factory found for eventType: {typeof(T).Name}");
            }

            return (AggregateRootMigrator<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
    }
```

now I can use it like this:
var dataMigrator = AggregateRootMigratorFactoryProvider.GetAggregateRootMigrator();
var result = dataMigrator.Migrate(data);